# Use LIKE in stored procedure with input parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 input parameters and I want to search users where a part o the username is `@Username` and a part of the name is `@Name` that this users part of usernames is `@Username` and part of name is `@Name`

```
SELECT *  
FROM tbl_answer
WHERE 
     an_del = 0 
     AND u_username = ISNULL(LIKE %@Username%, u_username) OR 
         u_name = ISNULL(LIKE @Name, u_name)
```

How I can use `LIKE` in this stored procedure?

Comment: ***WHAT*** database system is this for? SQL is just the query language used by **many** database systems - which one is it? MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something entirely different??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SearchAnswers
@Username nvarchar(20),
@Name nvarchar(20)
AS
SELECT *  
FROM tbl_answer
WHERE an_del=0 and u_username LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Username, u_username) + '%'
  OR u_name LIKE ISNULL(@Name, u_name)
```

[**Example for a SQLServer2008**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d7c6/2)

Comment: look for [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95d2a/1 and run sample this sample no return any data

Comment: If the procedure is called from a web application with arguments received from the user, the above concatenation of the SQL statement will make it vulnerable to SQL injection.   Erlang Sommarskog (MS SQL MVP) suggests using a built-in procedure sp_executesql to properly encapsulate arguments.  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic sql, for example sql server:

```
create procedure MyProc
(
  @Username varchar(30),
  @Name varchar(30)
)
as
begin
   exec ('SELECT * from tbl_answer where an_del=0 and 
           u_username=isnull(like ''%'+@Username+'%'',u_username) 
             or u_name=isnull(like '''+@Name+''',u_name)') 
end
```